# How open link in new tab in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I am using the RokSprocket module in a Joomla Template and I would need to open one photo by link in a different windows, for it, Could anybody help me?
Thanks in advance
Best Regards
Alejandro Castan
PS: Sorry for my little english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>var w;function openwindow(){w=window.open('http://www.w3schools.com/','', 'width=100,height=100');w.focus();}function myFunction(){w.resizeTo(500,500);w.focus();}</script></head><body><button onclick="openwindow()">Create window</button><button onclick="myFunction()">Resize window</button></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have uses the following to solve my problem:

```
<a href="/extensions/roksprocket/13-roksprocket-features/25-sample-content-1" target="_blank">
  <img src="/extensions/media/rokgallery/f/faa025be-fad2-4f7b-f7bc-2e3e9ad367a1/69f8dbe1-9a16-42d1-8ee7-ca0aa2be7992.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
</a>
```

Comment: Hi Maulik patel. First thanks for your answer. on the other hand and sorry for my ignorance but I am new in Joomla, for it, Should I add this code in the index.php? If it is like that What tad should I do it?(for example, body, head or something? Thanks again

Comment: Hi Maulik patel, Thanks for your help. I added the code target="_blank"  before href in my item.php and it works fine right now. Now I have to fix the new windows browser to the miodle(I see it to full size). Regards. Alejandro

Comment: Hi Msulik Patel, sorry to bother you again but I would hev to add this javascript code to resize the new windows(window.resizeTo(250, 250)) , for it, How and Where should I add this javascript code? Thanks